# Android Studio nested flavor

Tags: android, gradle

I want to create a nested flavor,
That mean i would like to create a base code a single flavor as multi-flavors form the single one

```
productFlavors {

        one{
             applicationId "com.example.my.one"

        }

        one-one{
             applicationId "com.example.my.one.one"
        }

        one-two{
             applicationId "com.example.my.one.two"
        }
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Possible answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41989396/1074998

Answer (score 1):

You can use flavourDimensions inside a particular type of productflavour

For example consider this build.gradle file:

```
android {
...

flavorDimensions "abi", "version"

productFlavors {
    freeapp {
        flavorDimension "version"
        ...
    }

    x86 {
        flavorDimension "abi"
        ...
    }
}
```

This will create following product flavours:

x86-freeapp-debug
x86-freeapp-release
arm-freeapp-debug
arm-freeapp-release
mips-freeapp-debug
mips-freeapp-release
x86-paidapp-debug
x86-paidapp-release
arm-paidapp-debug
arm-paidapp-release
mips-paidapp-debug
mips-paidapp-release

To know more about this you can use a nice documentation at:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you should try with flavor groups.

[Youtube Gradle playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuR1PJnGR-Igj4mNcr6_zDkQ3DTVA6wG5)

[Android tools reference](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors)

Something like this:

```
flavorGroups "group1", "group2"

    productFlavors {

        oneA {
            applicationId "com.example.my.one.A"
            flavorGroup "group1"
        }

        oneB{
             applicationId "com.example.my.one.B"
             flavorGroup "group1"
        }

        twoA{
             applicationId "com.example.my.two.A"
             flavorGroup "group2"
        }

        twoB{
             applicationId "com.example.my.two.B"
             flavorGroup "group2"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Other answers mistake NESTING FLAVORS with FILTERING of build variants!**

Unfortunately, there is no way to nest flavors, as far as I know. I suggested incorporating nested flavor name into its parent name and then filter the build variants - the same way as in the question (`one-one`, `one-two`, etc.). This will do the job. However, names of flavors will not be "atomic" in their meaning, so choose names with care.