# Does Android Studio support sub-flavors?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I have an Android Studio project that currently has 2 product flavors in the build.gradle as follows:

```
productFlavors {
        parent {
            applicationId "xxx.parent"

        }
        teacher {
            applicationId "xxx.teacher"
        }
    }
```

Both flavors have some common code under src/main

What I need is 1 more level of flavors, so I want under one flavor to have sub flavors which is 1 more level of customization (for some resources & some static variables)

So I want something similar to below:

```
productFlavors {
        parent {
            p1 {
                applicationId "xxx.parent.p1"
               }
            p2 {
                applicationId "xxx.parent.p2"
               }
        }
        teacher {
            t1 {
                applicationId "xxx.teacher.t1"
            }
            t2 {
                applicationId "xxx.teacher.t2"
            }
        }
    }
```

So my aim is to have 2 types of applications (teacher & parent) and each can be customized n times (they will differ by application id, resource files & static variables)

Any idea how can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you get any related answer or workaround for sub-flavors? In my case, I have a similar requirement, not as mention by peter.bartos. I have 10 flavors using similar code (parent), 2 sections - 1st (one flavor) - 2nd (other nine flavors) - 2 children. 2nd section also has some minor changes in the code so take it as sub-child or sub flavor.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Gradle supports sub flavors - **flavorDimensions**. E.g.:

```
flavorDimensions "server", "lib"

productFlavors {
    pub {
        dimension "server"
        minSdkVersion 19
        resValue "string", "app_version_name", mVersionName
    }
    beta {
        dimension "server"
        minSdkVersion 9
        resValue "string", "app_version_name", mVersionName + "beta"
    }
    xwalk {
        dimension "lib"
    }
    webkit {
        dimension "lib"
    }
```

Comment: In my case, I have a similar requirement, not as mention by you. I have 10 flavors using similar code (parent), 2 sections - 1st (one flavor) - 2nd (other nine flavors) - 2 children. 2nd section also has some minor changes in the code so take it as sub-child or sub flavor.

Comment: Unless I miss something, this code shows that there can be separate dimensions, but tells nothing about sub-flavoring